# Can I take pictures on a Canon T6i with no lens fitted?

Tags: canon

Currently I am trying James Millar's method of transferring old Super 8 movies by DSLR 1080p video of film in projector gate: https://vimeo.com/20950590  With projector lens still in place, Canon DSLR T6i (no lens) close to projector lens, I can get sharp image of tiny movie frame 6mm x 4mm in gate, lit from desk-lamp behind gate. However, I would appreciate input re best settings on Canon 6Ti?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's typically possible to take pictures with no lens attached. You can even make a digital pinhole camera by having a lens cap with extremely small hole in it!

The camera knows there is no attached lens, so it may omit the picture in the live view mode and replace it with a dark image.

Note if you're using external optics (projector lens), you need the image to be in focus at the sensor. Not sure how easy that's to achieve with the projector lens.

Comment: while technically you've answered the question (is it possible), I imagine the OP really wants to know _how_ to do it. Typically there's some setting that must be enabled in order to release the shutter when there's no lens attached. I'm not familiary with the setting in this case. Do you know what it's called and where it's accessed?

Comment: Thanks to Juhist who raised some of the potential issues. In fact, getting a sharp image with this projector lens was NO problem. Juhist unfortunately did not clarify the steps to take pic or video with Canon EOS T6i DSLR, As noted by osullic, that is my real question. Perhaps someone else can clarify how to do this?